# WordPress : comments on custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom post type called `"Movies"` thanks to ACF on WordPress and I would like to enable comments on these posts. I found some help here, modifying the `functions.php` file but it still doesn't work...

Here is the code I inserted in the `"only admin"` part. I have no clue if I'm doing this the right way...

I'm not a developer. Here's my code.

Thanks for your time.

```
// Enable comments in ACF
            add_action( 'init', 'movie' );
            function register_cpt_movie() {
                $labels = array(
                    'name' => _x( 'movie', 'movie' ),
                    'singular_name' => _x( 'movie', 'movie' ),
                    'add_new' => _x( 'Ajouter', 'movie' ),
                    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Ajouter une movie', 'movie' ),
                    'edit_item' => _x( 'Modifier', 'movie' ),
                    'new_item' => _x( 'Nouvelle movie', 'movie' ),
                    'view_item' => _x( 'Voir la movie', 'movie' ),
                    'search_items' => _x( 'Recherche', 'movie' ),
                    'not_found' => _x( 'Aucune movie trouvé', 'movie' ),
                    'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Aucune movie trouv&eacute;', 'movie' ),
                    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Service:', 'movie' ),
                    'menu_name' => _x( 'movie', 'movie' ),
                );

            $args = array(
                'labels' => $labels,
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'author', 'page-attributes' ),
                'public' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'menu_position' => 21,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => false,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'can_export' => true,
                'rewrite' => true,
                'capability_type' => 'page'
            );
            register_post_type( 'movie', $args );
```

Comment: Have you got any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the function call back for 'init' hook was wrong. It should no `register_cpt_movie` not `movie`.

The updated code is:

```
// Enable comments in ACF
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_movie' );
function register_cpt_movie() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'movie', 'movie' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'movie', 'movie' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Ajouter', 'movie' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Ajouter une movie', 'movie' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Modifier', 'movie' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'Nouvelle movie', 'movie' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Voir la movie', 'movie' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Recherche', 'movie' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'Aucune movie trouvé', 'movie' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Aucune movie trouv&eacute;', 'movie' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Service:', 'movie' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'movie', 'movie' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'author', 'page-attributes' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 21,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page'
    );
    register_post_type( 'movie', $args );
}
```

Comment: It worked ! However, it changed my word processor inside the "movie" post type. The content is gathered in a big block instead of being shared between several blocks (h2 and paragraphs).

Comment: @BenjaminRamet If it worked, can you check it for correct answer.